# sql apply multiple filter from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i apply filters in ExclusionFilter table dynamically on HotelDetails table.
e.g first row in ExclusionFilter table states exclude hotel id 1,
2nd row states excludes all hotels with location K,
3rd row excludes all hotels with location V and type 7 star
There fore the users will keep on adding the filters rows which has to applied on HotelDetails table

**HotelDetails table**

| Id | location | Hotel | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Hotel1 | 5 star |
| 2 | b | Hotel2 | 6 star |
| 3 | v | Hotel2 | 7 star |
| 4 | K | Hotel3 | 7 star |
| 5 | v | Hotel5 | 7 star |
| 6 | K | Hotel6 | 8 star |

**ExclusionFilter table**

| Id | location | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| null | k | null |
| null | v | 7 star |

Output will be

| Id | location | Hotel | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b | Hotel2 | 6 star |

I tried different ways by left join and using case but i cannot iterate through the filter and apply it on the tables

Comment: You likely can't write a static SQL statement for this, you'd realistically want to use dynamic SQL.  Are you putting this in a PL/SQL stored procedure?  Or would you need to dynamically assemble the SQL statement in the client application (in which case you should indicate what language you're using to build the client)?

Comment: will be stored proc which will be called client

Comment: I mean stored proc will be called by the client. Client will not be responsible for any sql task

Comment: I think the row with `Id=3` shouldn't be in the result set. Since, that should be filtered out because of the 3rd row of `ExclusionFilter` table.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `NOT IN` operator with subquery is needed such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM HotelDetails 
 WHERE ( Id, UPPER(location), UPPER(type) ) 
   NOT IN ( SELECT Id, UPPER(location), UPPER(type) FROM ExclusionFilter )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5bc1b5dfd494c7281a55341f1736b62)</kbd>